Jmeter load test design for simulate user with Azure AD
I would like to ask about the generated user with Azure authentication.
Previously I have test by use one simple account for simulate 100 user via Jmeter.
After that , the application change to Azure authen and I update the test plan to get the token from Azure Authentication completely.
So if I use that one access token for run 100 threads , is the same result /same test scope with my previous test (one simple account for simulate 100)?

It depends on your system under test implementation. Normally you should map 1 JMeter thread (virtual user) to 1 real user (credentials), otherwise your test results might not be accurate due to i.e. caching
So when you build a JMeter web test plan it's essential to configure JMeter to behave like a real browser
If you want to just replicate the test you made with 1 credentials and 100 virtual users using these credentials with Azure AD authentication - it will be more or less the same.
